# Firebase Notification Does Not Show When Application Run

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

This is my Code

```
 private void showNotification(String message) {

    NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle stil = new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle();
    stil.setBigContentTitle("Başıl");
    stil.bigText(message);
    Intent i=new Intent(this,Bilgi.class);
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,i,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
    builder.setAutoCancel(true);
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    builder.setTicker("selam dost.mesaj geldi");
    builder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL);
    builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    builder.setContentTitle("Bildirim");
    builder.setContentText(message);
    builder.setStyle(stil);
    NotificationManager notificationManager= (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(0,builder.build());



}
```

[image]

When i send a notification (if application is working (left side of picture)) my notify does not show. when application working at the background my notify shows. How can i solve this problem ? thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 6):

As stated in the [official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/notifications/android/console-audience#receive_and_handle_notifications) notifications are only added to the system tray automatically if the app runs in the background. If the app runs in the foreground the notification will instead be sent to the `onMessageReceived` method of your service.

So to summarize what will be done with Firebase Notifications based on app state:

- **Foreground**: `onMessageReceived` will handle the notification
- **Background**: Firebase will handle the notification and put it in the system tray for you

Comment: so what will change on my code ? can you help me ? thank you.

Comment: Where is the code for showing the notification called? In `onMessageReceived`? If so, did you verify that the message `String` is not empty.

Answer (score 2):

On your `onMessageReceived` method, you have to get the notification message body and pass it to the `showNotification(String message)` method.

like this:

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    String message = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();
    showNotification(message);
}
```

That way it will show the message you have set when sending the firebase notification.